# Checking if docker is logged into ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cli, dockerhub, amazon-ecr

Right now I'm grabbing the ecr password via a command and piping it in to `docker login` to authenticate my docker client with the ECR registry

```bash
 aws ecr get-login-password --region 'us-east-1' | \
 docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <my-aws-acct-id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Is there a command to tell if my docker client is already authenticated with ECR?

I tried to look at info in `docker info` and some other commands but it doesn't work to tell me if my docker is logged into ECR

The below doesn't work, but something like this in my shell script would be ideal:

```bash
   if docker info | grep -q "<my-aws-acct-id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; then
        echo "Already logged in to ECR ✅"
    else
        echo "Not logged in to ECR"
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way seems to be to check the docker's config.json, because the docker login command does not persist any kind of session.

You can do something like:

```bash
if cat ~/.docker/config.json | grep <your-account-id>.dkr.ecr.<your-region>.amazonaws.com; then
  echo "Already logged in to ECR ✅"
else
  echo "Not logged in to ECR"
fi;
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't work - there is an `auths` section in the `config.json` file but I think once you do an ecr docker login , it shows a`yourname.dkr.ecr.region.amazon` key in that file always - whether or not docker is logged into ECR

So you still can't really tell if it's for sure logged in